# AVG giving a Count instead of Average

Tags: sql-server, group-by

This is probably a silly mistake on my end but I can't quite figure it out on my on.
I'm trying to calculate average over a set of data pulled from a sub-query presented in the following way:

```
    TotalPDMPs  DefaultClinicID
       13996        -1
        134         23
        432         29
        123         26
        39          27
        13          21
        40          24
        46          30
        1           25
```

Now the average for each 'DefaultClinicID' calculated for 'TotalPDMPs' is the same as the data above. 
Here's my query for calculating the average:

```
select DefaultClinicID as ClinicID, AVG(TotalPDMPs)
 from
 (select count(p.PatientID) as TotalPDMPs, DefaultClinicID  from PatientPrescriptionRegistry ppr, Patient p
 where p.PatientID = ppr.PatientID
 and p.NetworkID = 2
  group by DefaultClinicID) p
 group by DefaultClinicID
```

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Your inner `select` will return only one record for each `DefaultClinicID` how do you expect different average for each `DefaultClinicID` in outer query

Answer (score 0):

The group by column is the same so it gets a count in the inner query by DefaultClinicID and then it tries to take an average of the same DefaultClinicID.

Does that make sense?  Any aggregation on that column while you group by the same thing will return the same thing.  So for clinic 23 the average calculation would be: 134 / 1 = 134.

I think you just need to do the average in your inner query and you get what you want. Or maybe avg(distinct p.patientID) is what you are after?

Comment: It makes sense. I'm trying to get the average of 'TotalPDMPs' over the entire row for each clinic. How can I modify my query to achieve this?

Comment: That is a tough question because I do not know the nature of your data.  Is the same patient in the PatientPescriptionRegistry multiple times?  What question are you trying to answer in more detail?  Average number of patients per clinic doesn't seem to make any sense with this data.  A distinct number of patients per clinic might make sense.  The % of distinct visits makes sense.  The % of patients at each clinic could make some sense as well.  The average number of patients per day at a clinic would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner sub-query you already grouped by DefaultClinicID,
So every unique DefaultClinicID has already only one row.
And the avg of x is x.